# Unitarily invariant norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-norms, unitary-matrices

> Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$, $M\in \mathbb{C}^{k\times k}$. If $X^HX=I_k$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is unitarily invariant, i.e., if for any unitary matrices $U, V$ we have
>   $$\|UYV\|=\|Y\| , \quad \forall Y\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$$
>   prove that
>
> $$X^H A X = \arg \min_M \| AX - XM \|$$

I know that $XX^HAX$ is the projection of $AX$ into $R(X)$, but I have no idea to use the properties of unitarily invariant norm. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that there exists an $n \times n$ unitary matrix $W$ such that $X = WJ$, where 
$$
J = \pmatrix{I_k\\0}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
X^HAX = (WJ)^HA(WJ) = J^H(W^HAW)J
$$
and also
$$
\|AX - XM\| = \|A(WJ) - (WJ)M\| \\
= \|W^H(AWJ - WJM)\| = \|(W^HAW)J - JM\|.
$$
In other words, it suffices to prove the following: if $B = W^HAW$, then 
$$
J^H B J = \arg\min_M \|BJ - JM\|.
$$
If we divide $B$ into blocks so that
$$
B = \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\ B_{21} & B_{22}}, \quad B_{11} \in \Bbb C^{k \times k}
$$
then we find that
$$
J^HBJ = B_{11}, \quad BJ - JM = \pmatrix{B_{11} - M\\B_{21}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!